# ¿Por cada tabla creada se tiene que crear un modelo?

Tags: laravel, orm

Estoy utilizando las migraciones de laravel, tengo 16 tablas (relacionadas entre sí) y me preguntaba si por cada tabla debe de existir un modelo o si solo debería crearle modelos a las tablas que más frecuente. Lo pregunto por el tema de las relaciones, sobre todo, que en los modelos se especifica con BelongsTo, HasMany y HasOne.

Por el momento tengo los modelos que más utilizaré.

[image: Migraciones y modelos]

Comment: Lo *"bonito"* de usar un ORM es que no necesitas *"tocar"* la base de datos tú mismo... si tienes un ORM, por qué no usar directamente tus objetos como entidades y quitarte de encima toda la parte de gestión de la base de datos, delegándola al ORM? Te evitas escribir un montón de código SQL y además, los ORM suelen estar bien depurados y libres de errores. De hecho, los ORM se usan precisamente para evitar tener que hacer toda la parte de acceso a la base de datos, no le veo sentido a meter todo el ORM y luego seguir escribiendo tú mismo todas las consultas

Comment: Es decir, crear los 16 modelos para las 16 tablas?

Comment: Cual es la alternativa entonces? Crear 16 repositorios, 16 servicios y 16 objetos con consultas SQL repetitivas y con posibilidades de añadir errores que el ORM seguramente no tenga? Yo lo veo claro eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Es necesario crear un modelo *Eloquent* para cada tabla**, salvo excepciones (tablas que representan la relación de muchos a muchos, por ejemplo).
Los ORM *necesitan mapear* de una u otra manera las relaciones que hay entre las tablas de la base de datos y para el caso de *Eloquent*, esto se hace con los modelos que deben incluir las correspondientes relaciones.

Lo importante para usar el ***ORM Eloquent*** son los modelos, las migraciones son un mecanismo que proporciona Laravel que puedes o no usar para generar/actualizar la BD.
De hecho, al comando *artisan* para crear modelos *Eloquent*, se le puede añadir un *flag* para crear al mismo tiempo la migración (y el seeder si se usa):

```
php artisan make:model NombreModelo -m
```

o con migración y seeder:

```
php artisan make:model NombreModelo -ms
```

La base de datos también puede crearse a través de scripts SQL.

Puedes optar por crear todos los modelos y relaciones desde el principio (cada vez que añades una tabla o modificas relaciones entre entidades de la base de datos) o ir añadiéndolas según las necesitas.
Si al final no usas alguna de las relaciones y sólo usas el ORM, será porque tu diseño relacional no es el correcto.

Comment: Gracias por leer y responderme :)